# Estimating a secret with before/after interchanging noises

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, noise

$\newcommand{\Var}{\mathrm{Var}}\newcommand{\E}{\mathrm{E}}$
For $n+1$ iid "noise" variables $X_0,\dots,X_n$ from the normal distribution  $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and a "secret" $s$ which is some small number, say that we are given the following series of $n$ values:
$$Y_1,\dots,Y_n=(s+X_0-X_1),\, (s+X_1-X_2),\dots,\, (s+X_{n-1}-X_n)$$
and we want to estimate $s$.
(If you want some intuition/example: say that I have a safe and there are two thieves stealing from me, one is the neutral thief and the other is the greedy thief. Every day the greedy thief steals $s$ coins, while the neutral thief steals/gives $X_i$ coins every evening and returns them in the next morning. Then $Y_i$ is the difference between the balances of two consecutive days measured at midnight. We want to estimate the damage caused by the greedy thief.)

At first I thought the best estimation should probably just be the average, but then I realized that computing the average of every sequence of $n/2$ consecutive values and averaging these averages results in lower variance. (Assume for simplicity that $n=2m+1$ is odd.)
$$\Var(\sum_{i=1}^nY_i/n)=\Var(s+(X_0-X_n)/n)=2/n^2$$
$$\Var\left(\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{m+1}\frac{\sum_{i=j}^{j+m}Y_i}{m+1}}{m+1}\right)=
\frac{\Var\left(\sum_{j=1}^{m+1}X_{j+m}-X_{j-1}\right)}{(m+1)^4}=
\frac{\Var\left(\sum_{j=m+1}^{2m+1}X_j-\sum_{j=0}^{m}X_j\right)}{(m+1)^4}=\frac{2}{(m+1)^3}$$
and we have that $(m+1)^3>(2m+1)^2$ for every $m\geq 2$.

After realizing the problem is not trivial I tried to compute the MLE but to no avail, I reached a derivative of the form (up to constants)
$$\E_{X_0}\left[-s\prod_{i=1}^nf(X_0-Z_i+i\cdot s)\right]$$
where $f$ is the normal PDF and $Z_i=\sum_{j=1}^i Y_i$, but I don't know how to continue.

I was wondering if the estimator above (average of averages) is optimal in some sense or if there is yet another more interesting estimator to this problem.

Edit: Apparently the estimator above (average of averages) is not optimal. I tried to find the optimal convex combination estimator of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n w_iY_i$ where $\sum_{i=1}^n w_i=1$ (obviously unbiased), calculated the variance $w_1^2+w_n^2+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(w_{i+1}-w_i)^2$ and used Lagrange multipliers + Thomas algorithm (tridiagonal matrix) to arrive at the solution $w_i=\frac{6i(n+1-i)}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$.
Looking at $1/\Var$, the most significant term appears to be $n^3/12$ as opposed to $n^3/16$ from before, so it only seems better by a small constant factor (asymptotically).

Comment: What is the objective function? Looks like $s$ has no role here, just an arbitrary shift on $Y_{i}$, that is  $Y^{'}_{i}=Y_{i}-s$. It is a recurrence equation $Y^{'}_{i} = X_{i-1} -  X_{I}$, which is generative.

Comment: @patagonicus The objective is to estimate the hidden patameter s, which is indeed just a small shift to all values. I think both the MVUE and MMSE estimator could be interesting.
I'm sorry but I don't know what a generative equation is. I was hoping for an explicit solution as this problem seems pretty natural to me.